# Django mysql prepared statements

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hello i trying to use mysql prepared statements in django.

I made a following class:

```
class PreparedStatement(object):

    def __init__(self,name,query):
        self.name = name
        self.query = query
        self.vars = []
        self.prepare()

    def setVar(self,name,var):
        name = "@%s" % name
        if name not in self.vars:
            self.vars.append(name)
        SQL = "SET %s = " % (name)
        self.__executeQuery(SQL+" %s;",var)

    def prepare(self):
        SQL = "PREPARE %s FROM " % self.name
        self.__executeQuery(SQL + " %s ;", self.query)

    def execute(self):
        SQL = "EXECUTE %s " % self.name

        if len(self.vars):
            params = ""
            for var in self.vars:
            params += var + ", "
            params = params[:-2]
            SQL += "USING %s " % params
        result =  self.__executeQuery(SQL)
        self.vars = []
        return result

    def __executeQuery(self,query,*args):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        if args:
            cursor.execute(query,args)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        return cursor
```

and i use it like this:

```
getDiscountsById = PreparedStatement("getDiscountsById","""SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1""")
getDiscountsById.setVar("id",5)
result = getDiscountsById.execute()
```

It is working fine for first loaded page , but after changing url or reloading page MySQL returns prepared statement not found error.

Where could be the problem? Is there any solution ?

Thanks for responses and sorry for my english :D

Comment: Why are you using prepared statements? Is it for a performance benefit or to write raw SQL without exposing SQL injection vulns?

Comment: @Thomas
It is school assigment , I can't use ORM and I have to use prepared statesments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are building the PreparedStatement object outside of a View and accessing it as a global.

You need to be aware that django has no concept of connection pooling, and every page view uses a brand new database connection. MySQL prepared statements only exist for the life of the connection/session in which they are defined. Hence, the first pagview loads the module that the PreparedStatement is in, and puts it in the DB, but the second connection tries to execute a statement that was prepared in a previous connection which obviously fails.

To fix this, create the PreparedStatement in the view you need it in, or use something like this (Doing it a bit more pythonically, not imitating PHP):

```
class PreparedStatement(object):

    def __init__(self, name, query, vars):
        self.name = name
        self.query = query
        self.vars = vars

    def prepare(self):
        SQL = "PREPARE %s FROM " % self.name
        self.__executeQuery(SQL + " %s ;", self.query)

    def get_prepared(self):
        # store a map of all prepared queries on the current connection
        return getattr(connection, "__prepared", default={})

    def execute(self, **kwvars):

        if not self.name in self.get_prepared().keys()
           # Statement will be prepared once per session.
           self.prepare()

        SQL = "EXECUTE %s " % self.name

        if self.vars:
            missing_vars = set(self.vars) - set(kwvars)
            if missing_vars:
                raise TypeError("Prepared Statement %s requires variables: %s" % (
                                    self.name, ", ".join(missing_variables) ) )

            param_list = [ var + "=%s" for var in self.vars ]
            param_vals = [ kwvars[var] for var in self.vars ]

            SQL += "USING " + ", ".join( param_list )

            return self.__executeQuery(SQL, *param_vals)
        else:
            return self.__executeQuery(SQL)

    def __executeQuery(self,query, *args):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        if args:
            cursor.execute(query,args)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        return cursor
```

And use it like this

```
# Global
getDiscountsById = PreparedStatement(
     "getDiscountsById",
     "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1",
     vars=["id"] # List out the names of the placeholders. This will assist in error checking.
)

#local to a view
result = getDiscountsById.execute(id=5)
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this but it should run or be easy to enough to tweak to run.

Comment: thank you for your explanation and solution. It is not working like this and i dont understand changes in working with variables. But i rewrite my solution a little bit and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Thomas i get it working like this:

```
class PreparedStatement(object):

    def __init__(self,name,query):
        self.name = name
        self.query = query
        self.vars = []

    def setVar(self,name,var):
        name = "@%s" % name
        if name not in self.vars:
            self.vars.append(name)
        SQL = "SET %s = " % (name)
        self.__executeQuery(SQL+" %s;",var)

    def prepare(self):
        SQL = "PREPARE %s FROM " % self.name
        self.get_prepared().append(self.name)
        self.__executeQuery(SQL + " %s ;", self.query)

    def get_prepared(self):
        try:
            getattr(connection, "__prepared")
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(connection,"__prepared",[])
        finally:
            return getattr(connection, "__prepared")

    def f_execute(self):
        return self.execute().fetchall()

    def execute(self):
        if not self.name in self.get_prepared():
            self.prepare()
        SQL = "EXECUTE %s " % self.name
        if len(self.vars):
            params = ""
            for var in self.vars:
                params += var + ", "
            params = params[:-2]
            SQL += "USING %s " % params
        result =  self.__executeQuery(SQL)
        self.vars = []
        return result

    def __executeQuery(self,query,*args):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        if args:
            cursor.execute(query,args)
        else:
            cursor.execute(query)
        return cursor
```

using remained the same:

```
getDiscountsById = PreparedStatement("getDiscountsById","""SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1""")
getDiscountsById.setVar("id",5)
result = getDiscountsById.execute()
```